# Improve Two sum problem using Map in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve Two sum problem using scala

```
  val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
  val map = collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
  val sum = 9

  for {
    i <- 0 until list.size
  } yield {
    map.get(sum - list(i)) match {
      case None                => map += (list(i) -> i)
      case Some(previousIndex) => println(s" Indexes $previousIndex $i")
    }
  }
```

Can anyone suggest an O(n) solution without using mutable map using scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to solve "Two sum problem" - meaning you need from given list find two numbers which gives sum equal to given, can go with:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val sum = 9

val set = list.toSet
val solution = list.flatMap { item => 
  val rest = sum - item
  val min = Math.min(item, rest)
  val max = Math.max(item, rest)
  if (set(rest)) Some(min, max) else None 
}.toSet
println(solution)
```

Print result:

```
Set((4,5))
```

ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/LA6P3eh/0

**UPDATE**
The result required to return indices not values:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val sum = 9

val inputMap = list.zipWithIndex.toMap
val solution = list.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case (item, itemIndex) =>
  inputMap.get(sum - item).map { restIndex => 
    val minIndex = Math.min(itemIndex, restIndex)
    val maxIndex = Math.max(itemIndex, restIndex)
    minIndex -> maxIndex
  }
}.toSet
println(solution)
```

Printout: `Set((3,4))`

ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/LA6P3eh/1

Comment: need to print index of elemets and not elements

Comment: @coder25 Ok, I see. Thanks, give me please several minutes to fix it

Comment: @coder25 I've updated the answer. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: does not work if sum =7, return Seq((1,4) ,(2,3))

Comment: @coder25 Why not it? It does -  1 and 4 indexes it's - 2 and 5 numbers; 2 and 3 indexes it's 3 and 4 numbers

Comment: Can you please explain the lines```val minIndex = Math.min(itemIndex, restIndex)
    val maxIndex = Math.max(itemIndex, restIndex)
    minIndex -> maxIndex```

Comment: @coder25 Sure - it's for unification same num pairs like `(1, 4)` and `(4, 1)` - so it will give always `(1 - minIndex, 4 - maxIndex)` and duplicates at the end will be removed because of using `toSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as follows for the first result:

```
object Solution extends App {
  def twoSums(xs: List[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int,Int)] = {
    @annotation.tailrec def go(zipped: List[(Int,Int)], map: Map[Int,Int] = Map.empty): Option[(Int,Int)] = {
      zipped match {
        case Nil => None
        case (ele, idx) :: tail =>
          map.get(target - ele) match {
            case Some(prevIdx) => Some((prevIdx, idx))
            case None => go(tail, map + (ele -> idx))
          }
      }
    }
    go(xs.zipWithIndex)
  }

  val res = twoSums(List(1,2,3,4,5), 9)
  println(res)
}
```

Or via `foldLeft` for all results:

```
object Solution extends App {
 def twoSums(xs: List[Int], target: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
   xs.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((Map.empty[Int,Int], List.empty[(Int,Int)])) {
     case ((map, results), (ele, idx)) =>
       map.get(target - ele) match {
         case Some(prevIdx) =>(map, (prevIdx, idx) :: results)
         case None =>  (map + (ele -> idx), results)
       }
   }
 }._2

  val res = twoSums(List(1,2,3,4,5), 9)
  println(res)
}
```